# Easily view Kubernetes pod assignment

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any command I can run to easily see which pods are assigned to which node?  As I mess around with resource requests and limits,  it would be very helpful to visualize how pods have been assigned to cluster members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the `-o wide` flag of `kubectl get`?

Answer (score 0):

The command used to get the information about a pod is :

```
kubectl get pods
```

in order to get the details of the node it is assigned to we can use the -o flag which is used to format the output. The command will be :

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

you can also describe the node to get info about the pods in it:

```
kubectl describe nodes
```